# Google Cloud Storage - Getting Download link from Signed Url with Generation No

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I use Google Cloud Storage Apis. I create Signed Url like this;

```
 var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("username@iam.gserviceaccount.com").FromPrivateKey(PrivateKey));
        var urlSigner = UrlSigner.FromServiceAccountCredential(credential);
        string url = urlSigner.Sign(bucketName, "Sample.txt", TimeSpan.FromDays(7));

        var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response  = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

it's ok. But I can't use Generation No for versions.

This is normal download without signed url;
I looking for "IfGenerationMatch = " on Signed Url

```
 await client.DownloadObjectAsync(
             bucket: bucketName,
             objectName: sourcePath,
             destination: destinationPath,
             progress: progress,
             options: new DownloadObjectOptions()
             { ChunkSize = 1048576, Range = rangeHeaderValue, IfGenerationMatch = data.GenerationNo }
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), the signed URLs can only access resources in Cloud Storage through XML API endpoints.

The `IfGenerationMatch` precondition is only present in the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions#_JSONAPI), as such, you will not find it using the signed URLs. You would need to use the `x-goog-if-generation-match` precondition since that's the equivalent in the [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions#_XMLAPI).